# OpenCV insufficient memory crash on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, out-of-memory, objective-c++

I have created a fisher face recognizer using the opencv contrib framework. I am having trouble training the model. When I call the train function the app crashes with the following error message.

```
 FaceDetector(1872,0x1b625bb80) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=2016002048) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
OpenCV(3.4.0-dev) Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 2016000000 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /Users/Name/Desktop/OpenCVBuild/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 55
OpenCV(3.4.0-dev) Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in create, file /Users/mustafa/Desktop/OpenCVBuild/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 436
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.0-dev) /Users/Name/Desktop/OpenCVBuild/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:436: error: (-215) u != 0 in function create

(lldb)
```

Here is the code I am using to train the model...

```
-(void) trainFaceRecognitionModel2 {
    NSArray * imageArray2;
    imageArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1781"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1782"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1783"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1784"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1785"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1786"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1787"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1788"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1789"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1790"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1791"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1792"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1793"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1794"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1795"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1796"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1797"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1798"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1799"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1800"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1801"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"1801"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"1802"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1803"], nil];

    std::vector<cv::Mat> images = vector<cv::Mat>();
    std::vector<int> labels;

    for (UIImage* image in imageArray2) {
         cv::Mat grayMat;
        cv::Mat imageMat;

        UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

        cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        images.push_back(grayMat);
        labels.push_back(2);


      //  [trainArray addObject:images];
        printf("training model...");

    }

    model2 -> train(images, labels);

}
```

I have used some of Xcode's tools to figure out that at the peak of training I am using as much as 6 GB! How would I reduce the amount memory needed and get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here, I've got as far as seeing that UIImageToMat(image, imageMat); add a lot of memory, that isn't freed afterwards. Even a manual .release on the mat doesn't clear out all of the memory.

Comment: As a temporary solution I lowered the amount of images. I will see if I can find a more practical solution